# MSI/EXE app on Windows store cannot show the correct installation status

Tags: installation, windows-installer, exe, windows-store

I've published my exe app to the windows store as following step:
[Publish your app in the Microsoft Store](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/publish/publish-your-app/overview?pivots=store-installer-msi-exe)

After successfully install it on windows store, the "Install" button on windows store page is greyed and show "Installed", it is correct. But If I reopen the windows store , the "Install" button is enabled again. How can I let the windows store know my app has been installed? Can anyone help me ? Thanks.